# Arcobjects initializing license error

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, license

I have ArcObjects .NET code that is running on a machine with ArcGIS for Server 10.1.

The application worked on the dev server.
But when I moved to Test server, I am not able to initialize the licenses.

This is the code I am using

```
RuntimeManager.Bind(ProductCode.Server);
bool succes = false;
AoInitialize arcObjectInitEnv = new AoInitializeClass();
if (arcObjectInitEnv.IsProductCodeAvailable(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeStandard) == esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseAvailable)
{
    status = arcObjectInitEnv.Initialize(licenseCode);
}
else
{
    throw exception(...);
}
```

I am sure I authorized the server right.
and I am able to run ArcGIS server manager.
And test the services and they are working fine.

I compile as "Any Cpu" , which is the same I used for Dev.
Is there tool that give me "availablity" for server, like desktop?
I didn't install ArcObjects SDK on the test server, because I assume it is not required there. Is that true?

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you try changing `esriLicenseProductCodeArcStandard` to `esriLicenseProductCodeArcServer`?

Comment: Shoud you compile it in x86? due it is ArcObjects

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the function

RunRuntimeManager.BindLicense(ProductCode.Server);

then get rid of the code related to AoInitialize arcObjectInitEnv = new AoInitializeClass();

this funtion can be used if you are not going to use any extension.